# Can qemu-system-riscv add a network device now?

Tags: qemu, riscv

When I use `qemu-system-riscv`, I find that the `-net` option doesn't work. Does it means that `qemu-system-riscv` does not support to add network devices?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, qemu-system-riscv supports only HTIF console or SiFive UART, check https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu  (you may try to define additional consoles / UARTs and start old classic [PPP over serial](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html))

> [Current limitations:](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu#current-limitations)
>
> The current RISC-V board definition provides only an HTIF console device. Support for other HTIF-based devices has been removed from riscv-linux; as a result, QEMU no longer supports them either.

Actually there are two so-named "boards" (definitions of virtual machine, its memory and its peripheral devices) for RISC-V in qemu, both are here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/tree/master/hw/riscv

- [riscv-qemu/hw/riscv/riscv_board.c](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/blob/master/hw/riscv/riscv_board.c) ("RISC-V Generic Board", "Spike"): 3 serial devices, cpus of "rv64imafd" instruction set with reset, main RAM @ 0x80000000, boot ROM, dummy IPI RAM @ 0x40001000, kernel loader, rtc clock @ 0x40000000+8, htif registers at address defined in ELF. "smp" is listed but I'm not sure that it is implemented. There is no any standard bus for plugging in some network devices; and for VirtIO devices there is single line of code which is a comment `/* TODO: VIRTIO */`

> ```
>  * This provides a RISC-V Board with the following devices:
>  *
>  * 0) HTIF Test Pass/Fail Reporting (no syscall proxy)
>  * 1) HTIF Console
>  *
>  * These are created by htif_mm_init below.
>  *
>  * This board currently uses a hardcoded devicetree that indicates one hart.
> ```

- [riscv-qemu/hw/riscv/sifive_board.c](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/blob/master/hw/riscv/sifive_board.c) ("SiFive U500 SDK Compatible"): kernel loader, cpu of "rv64imafd" with reset, RAM & boot ROM, dummy IPI and PLIC mem, 3 serial ports, 2 plic devices in config_string, rtc and uart (`sifive_uart_create`), timer. Exactly same implementation of VIRTIO devices: `/* TODO: VIRTIO */`

> ```
>  * This provides a RISC-V Board with the following devices:
>  *
>  * 0) UART comptible with that expected by the SiFive U500 SDK
>  *
>  * This board currently uses a hardcoded devicetree that indicates one hart.
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have found this issue and now I am using lowRISC-chip as my lab platform to add ethernet support. :-)

Comment: @ZishuoWang, does lowRISC-chip has any network support? Or AXI interfaces? If my answer provide enough details to check that there is no network support in qemu for risc-v, you may (or may not) accept it by clicking "v"-shaped button left to it, near voting up/down buttons, to mark the question as answered/closed.